# How to set the "base class list" in derived class __init__ in Python?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have a class that extends list; simplifying as much as possible, it looks like:

```py
class grid(list):
   def __init__(self, data):
       "If data is an int, create empty grid of size data; if data is a list, initialize grid with that data."
       if type(data) == grid:   # make a new copy of the old grid instance 'data'
           self += data
           self.__dict__ |= data.__dict__.copy()
       elif type(data) == list:
           self += data
           self.score = sum(len(row) for row in data)
       elif type(data) == int:
           self += [[] for _ in range(data)]  # NOTE: [[]]*data creates multiple references to the same empty row!
           self.score = 0
       else: raise Exception("data must be integer or list!")
```

It works but I find it awkward that I must (?) use `+=` to "append" the content I want to create to the initially empty "base list":
If use, e.g., `self = data`, then `self` becomes a basic list and setting attributes like "self.score = ..." will result in an error.

I think and/or know that I could also use `super().__init__(data)` to copy the given initial data into the underlying list. But it looks like an overkill, unnecessarily "heavy". (Isn't my way of doing it (much) more efficient? After all, the empty list is already there, wouldn't `super().__init__` create an entire new one?) For the data=int case, should I then say `super().__init__([...])` creating *two* copies of the new "empty" list: the one given as argument to super.init and the copy created by that function!?

Also, is my code for creating a copy of an existing instance of `grid`, in particular, `self__dict__ |= data.__dict__.copy()`, the way to go? In reality, there are many more attributes in addition to `.score`, some of them being lists. I know that I must (?) use individual `copy()`s for each of them to effectively create new copies of these and not just references to the attributes of the old instance. Should I use some `deepcopy` module to do this in a "cleaner"(?) way?

EDIT/UPDATE: To clarify, my question was whether there is a way to **assign** a value to the base list (in the present case, or base-whatever in the general case), as we assign values to the other components (i.e., attributes) of the object (for example, `self.__inner_list = list(data)`.). The type of the "rows" (elements of the list) is irrelevant, I used [] in the empty grid for simplicity but actually the rows are sets in my real code, but I also allow lists and dicts - in particular because I must/want/do output empty rows using the usual mathematical notation for empty sets, "{}" (which however represents an empty `dict` in Python), and for consistency also want to allow this as input. From the comments it appears that there is no such way to "simply" **assign** a value to the base object (which is logical, after all).

Comment: I'm not sure I would use inheritance for this. While a list of lists can be used to *represent* a grid, is it really the case that *all* lists of lists are grids? I would probably 1) Define a class that wraps a list of lists. 2) Have `__init__` take a list of lists as an argument 3) Define separate class methods that take an existing grid or an int as arguments to return a new grid. 4) Define the methods that make sense for grids, rather than just assuming all `list` methods are valid. (E.g., do you really want to allow `g = grid(3); g.append("foo")`?)

Comment: `__init__` does not *create* the list; it *initializes* it. `list.__new__` is what calls `type.__new__` to actually create the new list, which gets passed to `list.__init__` to have the values from the given iterable added to it.

Comment: @chepner: No-one says that all lists of lists are grids but, *my* grids *are* lists of lists. How to define a class that wraps "list of lists", that's not an existing type (considering "list[list]" just an annotation - but yes, I could use that). And it does not change the question. 3) defining e.g. grid().empty(n) to create an empty grid os size n is bloatware and weird because grid() would already initialize an empty list. OK-one might use grid.empty(n). 4) Yes, I have many methods for this class, but I wanted to keep the example as simple as possible.

Comment: No, my question is, do you consider `[[1], [2,3,4,5], [6,7]]` a grid? You already are creating a list of empty lists when the argument is an integer; I'm just transferring that to a separate method to avoid complicating `__init__`, which you want to keep as simple as possible. (Ideally, there is one "canonical" way to initialize a grid, and all the others can be implemented in terms of the canonical way; see my answer as an example.)

Comment: @ `__init__` / `__new__`: yes, I was considering that. Still, I fear a performance hit when using super().__init__, and that should mean it's not a good way to do the most basic thing than can be done.

Comment: There's no performance hit to using `super().__init__`. It's just another call to a bult-in method, just like `self += ...` is a call to `self = self.__iadd__(...)`.

Comment: @ "No...": yes, actually, these grids do have rows of variable length (cf. the "score"), but indeed I do validity checks on the contents of the rows. (Also the number of rows must be odd, and the maximum value in a row depends on its index, and the rows are actually sets rather than lists, etc etc ; in my full program I do all these checks but again, that's not the question here! The question is, how to *assign* the initial value to the base list, which is just one part of the object. OK, I think I understand I should indeed use super().__init__ .

Comment: @ "There's no..." : but what does that built-in method super().__init__ other than call self.__iadd__?

Comment: I don't know exactly *how* `list.__init__` works, only that one of the things it *does* is copy whatever iterable is passed as an argument into the new list.

Comment: If you have validity checks, then you probably don't want the inherited `append` method to be called to circumvent them. You really don't want to be inheriting from `list` just because it's convenient to avoid implementing similar methods.

Comment: I inherit from list because my grid *is* a list (and I don't want to assume more; it turns out that it should be a list of sets but can actually also be a list of lists and even some of the rows may be dicts, among other reasons, because we want to display empty sets as {} (which actually is a dict) rather than set(), and for consistency, allow this also as input.

Comment: A list is quite different from a list of any particular type of item. Is `["foo", 3, [], {}]` a grid?

Comment: It's perfectly legit to allow rows of different "type" as initial data and convert all of them to some "standard" type. Consider `numpy.array` where the initial data given as argument(s) can be a list holding a mixture of integers, floats, and/or even lists or other types, and/or additional parameters. Same here.

Comment: "Still, I fear a performance hit when using super().__init__" ... have you considered just using Numpy?

Comment: I'm not talking about initialization. I'm talking about someone creating a `grid` object, then using the exposed `list.append` method to modify it in ways incompatible with your *intended* use of a `grid`.

Comment: It comes across to me that this is not really one programming question, but instead multiple design decisions. Please keep in mind that this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: I'll second this: inheritance seems like the wrong approach here altogether

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring some other issues, I would write the class like this:

```
class grid(list):
   def __init__(self, lists: list[list]):
       self.extend([x] for x in lists)

   @classmethod
   def from_grid(cls, g: grid):
       # A grid is already a list of lists
       return cls(g)

   @classmethod
   def from_int(cls, n):
       return cls([[] for _ in range(n)])
```

---

A call like `list([1,2,3])` first uses `list.__new__` to create an empty list (ignoring the argument, though possibly using it to preallocate enough for the new list to hold the three values), then passes that new list and the given iterable to `list.__init__` to copy the values from the iterable into the new list. You can see this by overriding `__init__` to examine the value of `self` before and after calling `super().__init__`:

```
class A(list):
    def __init__(self, x):
        print(self)
        super().__init__(x)
        print(self)
```

Then

```
>>> a = A([1,2,3])
[]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you, but unless I'm wrong, (1) your `self.extend(...)` is no different from my `self += ...` ; (2) `list[list]` is just an annotation, meant to be something real in a future version, maybe; (3) the type / contents of the list and/or grid is not really relevant for my question; actually I want to allow list[list] and also dict, but will effectively cast all to the "real" type which is list[set]. I wondered whether there is a way to **assign** a value to the underlying list, just as I assign values to other attributes. Seems there's not, and super().__init__ should be used - got it!

Comment: `extend` and `+=` are similar, but I'm taking the extra step of creating copies of the sublists as well, so that your new instance of `grid` doesn't share references with he original. (If I don't, a change to a sublist in one grid is visible in the other.)

Comment: I could also have used `super().__init__([list(x) for x in lists])` instead.

Comment: This is all kind of moot, because I think you should be using composition instead of inheritance anyway. `class grid: def __init__(self, lists: list[list]): self._data = [list(x) for x in lists]`.

Comment: indeed I do use, in my original, `self += [ set(row) for row in data ]` ! :-)

Comment: Don't you mean `x.copy() for x in lists`?

Comment: Same thing assuming `x` is already a list, isn't it?